# Fill second form hidden fields with first form values (HTML, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add hidden fields in the second form and fill these fields (using java script) with the first form values before submission.

First form:

```
                    <form id="contactform" name="cform" class="contact-form clearfix form oswald normal antialiased" method="post" action="./contact/includes/contact-processs.php">
                    <div class="fullwidth clearfix">
                        <div class="f-left">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="f-right">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Hashtags / Target Audience"></textarea>
                    <div class="note"></div>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="darkertext" name="submit" onclick="loading()">GET STARTED</button>
                </form>
```

Second Form:

Comment: both form on same pages?

Comment: Yes, one is a contact form, the other is a PayPal form (I need the hidden fields in the paypal form to have the same values as the contact form)

Comment: can you show me your Both form html code so i will help you man?are you use jquery?

Comment: I've added the first form, the second form is a generic paypal subscription form( wont let me add above ) - I do use jQuery

Comment: which field you want to add in second form?

Comment: I'd like to copy the contents of name, email and message into 3 hidden fields in the PayPal form directly below this form

Comment: jquery is available in your app?

Comment: okey than tell me your second form id ?

Comment: okey i post answer tell me if any problem?

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not the best solution but you can try this.

```
<!--Form 1-->
<form onsubmit="fill()">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<!-- Form 2-->
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="nameHidden">
</form>

//Javascript code
function fill() {
   var element1 = document.getElementById("nameHidden");
   var element2 = document.getElementById("name");
   element1.value = element2.value;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, however I can't seem to get it working, the form 2 fields come up empty after submission

Comment: So you are submitting first form and you want second form data to be on second page? If I am wrong then please correct me.
And if possible attach a snapshot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addEventListener("change", function(){...}` to listen to input change and fill the other form on input value change.

Demo :

```js
paypalform.name.addEventListener("change", function(){
    contactform.name.value = paypalform.name.value;
});
paypalform.email.addEventListener("change", function(){
    contactform.email.value = paypalform.email.value;
});
paypalform.message.addEventListener("change", function(){
    contactform.message.value = paypalform.message.value;
});
```

```html
<form id="paypalform" name="cform" class="contact-form clearfix form oswald normal antialiased" method="post" action="./contact/includes/contact-processs.php">
  <div class="fullwidth clearfix">
  <div class="f-left">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="f-right">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
  </div>
  </div>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Hashtags / Target Audience"></textarea>
  <div class="note"></div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="darkertext" name="submit" onclick="loading()">GET STARTED</button>
  </form>

<!---------Second Form---------->
<form id="contactform" name="cform" class="contact-form clearfix form oswald normal antialiased" method="post" action="./contact/includes/contact-processs.php">
  <div class="fullwidth clearfix">
  <div class="f-left">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class="f-right">
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
  </div>
  </div>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Hashtags / Target Audience"></textarea>
  <div class="note"></div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="darkertext" name="submit" onclick="loading()">GET STARTED</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

on contactform submit all field

```
$("#contactform").on("submit",function(){
  var name=$(this).find("#name").val();
  var email=$(this).find("#email").val();
  var message=$(this).find("#message").val();

  var form2=$("#paypalform");

  form2.find("#name").val(name);
  form2.find("#email").val(email);
  form2.find("#message").val(message);

})
```

let me know it work or not